# CSSless mixin are undefined between less files

Tags: html, css, less, mixins

I downloaded CCSLess and a collection of mixin called elements.less.
When i try to use one of the mixin in my own quickStart.less file it says:

> .gradient is undefined
>   in quickStart.less on line 28, column 5:
>
> { .gradient;}

in the console it parses it in the right order:
the elements.less is parsed first.

and yet i am unable to call mixin which are located in a different file.

anyone knows why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you sure you have correctly imported elements.less ?
Try putting

```
@import "elements"
```

at the top of your file.

Comment: i don't know why i tried to script tag them both:     <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="styles/elements.less">
    <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="quickStart.less">

Comment: Glad it helped ! Indeed less.js does not let you use mixins defined in a file that was not imported using the `@import` rule.